# Code dosen't give output and keeps running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a code that would give me all the answers to [this question](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/sep/11/did-you-solve-it-try-your-cluck-at-these-chicken-problems)

My code:

```
import random 
hen = 3
rooster = 5
boolean = True
lst = []
while boolean == True:
  dicti = {}
  qian = 100
  lst = []
  i = random.randint(1,12)
  i2 = random.randint(4,25)
  i3 = random.choice(list(range(3,85,3)))
  qian -= i3/3
  qian -= i2*hen
  qian -= i*rooster
  if qian == 0:
    if 15*i + 9*i2 + i3 == 300:
      dicti["chick"] = i3
      dicti["hen"] = i2
      dicti["rooster"] = i
      lst += [dicti]
  if len(lst) == 4:
    boolean = False
```

I have the ranges set up to the highest numbers in the answer section in the link I provided,
but it seems to be in a infinite loop, any ideas where I went wrong?
I am happy to any answer.
THANK YOU! :)

Comment: Maybe you should print the value of `qian` in your loop and ask yourself what it would take to make it equal to zero.

Comment: It is very unlikely that `qian` ever becomes zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the loop will never because the ending condition is unreachable due to the list being set empty at the beginning of the loop.
just cancel the line where the list is set empty inside the loop and it should work:

```
import random 
hen = 3
rooster = 5
boolean = True
lst = []
while boolean == True:
    dicti = {}
    qian = 100
    i = random.randint(1,12)
    i2 = random.randint(4,25)
    i3 = random.choice(list(range(3,85,3)))
    qian -= i3/3
    qian -= i2*hen
    qian -= i*rooster
    if qian == 0:
        if 15*i + 9*i2 + i3 == 300:
            dicti["chick"] = i3
            dicti["hen"] = i2
            dicti["rooster"] = i
            lst += [dicti]
        if len(lst) == 4:
            boolean = False
```